# How to comment JSX code out in .js files in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, jsx

Unlike in webstorm, I'm unable to comment JSX code out in `.js` files in the Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Are you looking for a shortcut or just how to do it?

Comment: @erichardson30 I'd like to know how to do it! The shortcut comments code out by doing "//" but obviously that's not going to work. I'd like it to do "/* */" instead.

Comment: This one is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49121821/823321

Answer (score 101):

You can comment out JSX by {/**/}

Example :

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1 />
      {/* <Component2 /> */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

and then Component2 would be commented out

Comment: Yes but is there any way to do that through the shortcut Cmd+/ shortcut?

Comment: I've been searching around and don't see anything....I'll let you know when I stumble upon something for a shortcut

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6461 This is what I managed to find regarding the problem

Comment: Yeah...it seems to be an ongoing issue?

Answer (score 47):

Search `Babel JavaScript` in VS Code:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel

[image]

Install and `command + /` will comment jsx with `{ /* */ }`

Answer (score 26):

Try to disable all plugins, because they can change editor's behaviour. For example if use [Babel ES6/ES7](https://github.com/dzannotti/vscode-babel) plugin, editor comments `.jsx` syntax by `//` instead of `{/*`. You see see the issue [here](https://github.com/dzannotti/vscode-babel/issues/19).

Comment: I appear to have had this problem, where the VS Code commenting in JSX applied `{/*  */}` for several weeks, but then it stopped working. I did install Babel ES6/ES7 yesterday, so I just tried uninstalling it, and it's not back to normal. Any help?

Comment: @JonathanTuzman try to disable your VS plugins one by one.

Answer (score 14):

In `Visual Studio code` Hit `Cmd + /` if you are running on mac or place

```
{/* Your Code */}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The keyboard commands...

`Ctrl + /` - Windows & Linux
`Cmd  + /` - MacOS

...now work as expected for single line and block code by adding `{/* */}` around the selected lines.

It [has been fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6461) in recent [Insiders builds of Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders) and will make it into the next full release.

Comment: The same keyboard shortcut works in Atom too (probably not surprising as Visual Studio Code & Atom are both built on electron).

Comment: Can't get it to work in VS CODE.  Are you using any plugin that helps this out?

Comment: Works for me without any plugins on the most recent general release of VS Code.

Comment: Not working here

Answer (score 4):

{/*
this works, but only single line
*/}

Comment: Your answer is not different from the already well marked answer.

Comment: Multi-line comments using this syntax do work fine for me (with the `{/*` only on the first line, and `*/}` only on the last line).

Comment: Definitely supports multiline comment

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue until I converted the file language to Typescript React (typescriptreact).

If you want to configure this as the language for all .js files, add this to your settings.json (either globally, or at a project-level in /.vscode/settings.json).

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "typescriptreact"
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If You want to comment JSX syntax block, you can do like this

```
{
  /* <section>
     <header><h3>Contact Form</h3></header>
     <figure>
       <Form />
     </figure>
   </section> */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This also works

```
{
  //this.props.user.profileImage
  //? <img
  //    src={ this.props.user.profileImage }!
  //    alt=""
  //  />
  //: <FontAwesome name='smile-o' />
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go if you have {/* */} comments already present in the block being commented out.

Answer (score 3):

Currently in Visual studio code it could be done by pressing combination - Shift+Alt+A and comment "jsx" code it produces - {/**/} comments.

Answer (score 2):

If we press `cmd + /` by default vs code will do single line comments which can't be applied for JSX. Just install the below vs code extension it will be fine.

[vscode-language-babel](https://github.com/michaelgmcd/vscode-language-babel)

Answer (score 2):

In React "{}" allows us to use JavaScript Expressions, so we can comment the way we do in JavaScript.

Example:

```
{/* multi 
line 
comment 
*/}

{// single line comment
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Linux,
For a single line, Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

And for multiline, Select the snippets in VSCode
Just Hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>.

It works.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 2):

I spent few hours on this problem, and the easiest solution I found is the following:
Yes the problem is coming with the installation of Babel ES6/ES7 extension as many noticed,
and when you uninstall or deactivate it, VScode retrieves it's normal behavior:
Ctrl + / => Toggle Line Comment for line or block selected with `//` for JS, JSX, ... files;
Shift + Alt + A => Toggle Block Comment for line or block selected between `<!--` `-->`  in HTML files, between `/*` `*/` in JS expressions and between `{/*` `*/}` in JSX files for markup tags in render/return...
So if you want to keep Babel ES6/ES7 extension active and still have such a behavior:
You can parameter your own shortcut key-binding combination in the file keybindings.json
( File/Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts (or Ctrl+K+S) and then click the little file icon on top right
for selecting Open Keyboard Shortcuts wich opens keybindings.json)
where you use the VScode build-in command "editor.action.insertSnippet" as following:

```
[
    {
    "key": "shift+alt+a",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
        "snippet": "{/*\n ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT} \n*/}$0"
    },
    "when": "editorLangId == 'javascript' && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    }
]
```

Place the `/n` where you want in the expression for breaking lines, and the `$0` for final placement(s) of cursor.
Then save, and it's working straight :) only in JS and JSX files
If you want to specify another language just replace `'javascript'` in the `"when"` expression
by the one you want from this VScode Language Identifiers list :
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers
And of course if you want another snippet behavior : just replace the `{/*` by what you want in the `"args"` expression.

Answer (score 2):

First install Babel extension in VSCode, then select the line and use
**ctrl + /** in windows
and **cmd + /** in mac to comment

Comment: also ctrl + shift + /  will give you a  block comment.

Comment: I'm using VS Code v1.15.1 and I can still comment out using `Ctrl + /` **without** installing the Babel extension

Answer (score 1):

=>To **comment** a selected *single line* or *multi-lines* of code:

For **Windows** or **Linux** machine select the code and use:

1. `Ctrl + /`  to get comment pattern **//**
2. `Ctrl + Shift + A`   to get comment pattern {/*  */}

For **Mac** machine select the code and use:

1. `Cmd + /`  to get comment pattern **//**
2. `Cmd + Shift + A`   to get comment pattern {/*  */}

=> To **uncomment** the commented line(s) of code:
Just repeat the step, you used for commenting.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstall SUBLIME BABEL JOSH PENG and it work's

Befor: //

After:

{/*  */}

with React JavaScript and it's WORK :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For window follow these steps:

1. Select lines you bring under comment.
2. shift+{
3. shift+alt+a

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently vs code doesn't make comments automatically using `ctrl + /` or `cmd + /` on jsx so we have to write {/* text goes here */} manually

EDIT: Uninstall Babel extension from vs code and the jsx comments will start on `ctrl + /` or `cmd + /`

Answer (score 0):

What I haven't seen mentioned here is that you can use standard comments inside element tags.

```
<div //all
  className='foo bar foo-bar' //these
  id='foobar' //are
  style={{height: '100%'}} //valid
  //comments
/>
```