# How to comment/uncomment jsx (using keyboard `cmd /`) in VSC?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Can anyone tell me how to comment JSX code in VSC?

I looked at the articles listed at the bottom, none of them seem to give a concrete solution, and the ticket appeared to have been closed, claiming that the commenting/uncommenting function has been properly resolved on VSC. However, I am still having troubles after trying out the followings as suggested:

1. disable sublime-babel extension on VSC
2. Update my language to Javascript react
3. In user setting, added the followings:

   `"emmet.syntaxProfiles": { "javascript": "jsx" },`

   `"files.associations": {
       "*.js": "javascriptreact"
   },`

Any clue would be really appreciated. Exhaused all tricks. Thanks!

[How to you comment jsx code out in .js files in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483225/how-to-you-comment-jsx-code-out-in-js-files-in-vscode)

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6461

Comment: did you find the solution to this question?

Comment: This one is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38483225/823321

Comment: Find my solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483225/how-to-comment-jsx-code-out-in-js-files-in-vscode/63777644#63777644

Answer (score 1):

Select the text to be commented then press Ctrl+K and Ctrl+C.

Comment: it doesn't work. it gave me `// </div>` `// <div className="board-row">` etc

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to install React or Babel plugin?

Answer (score 0):

This might sound dumb but, have you tried re-installing VSCode? Commenting out JSX in a .js file works fine for me without any plugins. (I use windows)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue and for me the problem was the extension **Babel ES6/ES7**.
I've uninstalled that extension.

If that doesn't help you could try changing the Language Mode to **JavaScript React**

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalled **Babel ES6/ES7** work for me :)