# VS Code -- commenting .jsx syntax

Tags: visual-studio-code

I checked previous questions on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483225/how-to-you-comment-jsx-code-out-in-js-files-in-vscode) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49121821/how-to-comment-uncomment-jsx-using-keyboard-cmd-in-vsc) and VS Code's issues [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6461) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24047).

I still don't know how I can comment `jsx` syntax in VS Code by `cmd + /`. I tried syntax `JavaScript React` and `JavaScript Babel` and add:

```
"files.associations": {
        "*.js": "javascriptreact"
    },
```

into user settings. Nothing helped. When I check Developer Tools, there are no error messages.

[recording](https://i.imgur.com/56SaqfC.gif)

Comment: What software did you use for the gif? I usually don't get such good quality

Comment: I use [kap](https://getkap.co/)

Comment: It works for me, Remember Atom has this behavior, but VSCode looks a bit intelligent around this area. https://i.imgur.com/3D3lKhn.gifv. Also look at the plugins i have installed. There may be some plugin is that changing the behavior for you. I have no custom file associations defined. Also I am on the latest and greatest version of VSCode

Comment: This is really good idea, I will try it out. Thank you.

Comment: I had this issue because of [Babel ES6/ES7](https://github.com/dzannotti/vscode-babel) plugin. I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50090419/968379)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have [Babel ES6/ES7](https://github.com/dzannotti/vscode-babel) plugin installed, disable it. Editor comments `.jsx` syntax by `//` instead of `{/*`. You see see the issue [here](https://github.com/dzannotti/vscode-babel/issues/19).

Comment: @Green please, when you comment something and downvote answers, check some information. You don't need Babel plugin for syntax highlighting, because VS Code has built-in support for JSX and TSX.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me, Remember Atom has this behavior, but VSCode looks a bit intelligent around this area.

[image: Working]

I have no custom file associations defined. Also I am on the latest version of VsCode. Make sure you have no additional addins that takeover and change the behavior

Comment: it might be because you use .jsx extension for the file. Most of the people use .js instead.