# how to comment reactjs mark up code in visual code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to comment `react js` code especially mark up on `VS` code. When i use command `Ctrl+k,c` it uses `//` to commit the react markup. can you please suggest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to comment jsx code out in .js files in VSCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483225/how-to-comment-jsx-code-out-in-js-files-in-vscode)

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File => Preferences => settings`
Find edit in setting `json` file and use this command

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.js": "typescriptreact"
  }
```

Now you can use `Ctrl+k,c` command to comment markup of react `js`