# VS Code - Key Bindings - my own Block comment

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments, key-bindings, keymapping, latte

I am using VS Code Version: 1.40.0.

for quicken up my development I would need to set my own keybinding for block comment when I am in **.phtml** file.

I managed to get into *keybindings.json*, put this inside:

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+q",
    "command": "editor.action.blockComment",
    "blockComment": [ "{*<!--", "-->*}" ],
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname == .phtml"
}
```

I got the part

```
"blockComment": [ "{*<!--", "-->*}" ],
```

from here [How to customize comment block characters in visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822552/how-to-customize-comment-block-characters-in-visual-studio-code).

It might be a complete trash. I just tried. It doesn't work, of course.

**Optimal solution:** 
Even better would be, if the default **key** parameter would stay the same (*shift+alt+a*) for toggle block comment and in **.phtml** files i would get my desired result ("`{*<!-- -->*}`"). 
If I think about it, there is default block comments for **.css**, **.html** etc, so there must be a way to put my condition somewhere, rigth?

I would be very glad for any help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Find my solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483225/how-to-comment-jsx-code-out-in-js-files-in-vscode/63777644#63777644

Comment: Upvoted. I have the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @ARS81 Unofrtunately not. I started to use Sublime text ... and it was much more simple there ... but I am going to go back to VS Code probably ... and I would be glad if someone get to the solution ... 
I need to check CyberChris link yet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the best would be to write your own [Language Extension plugin](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview) for .phtml files and set the desired comment pairs in its [configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide).

Not a real solution but until then, here's my supper ugly workaround (use at your own risk):

Put this in your *keybindings.json*

```json
  {
    "key": "ctrl+numpad_divide",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(\\s*)({\\*<!-- (.*) -->\\*})?(.*)/$1${3:-{*<!-- }$4${4:+ -->*\\}}/s}"
    },
    "when": "editorTextFocus && editorHasSelection && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /phtml?$/"
  }
```

This way `ctrl + /` can be used for comment/uncomment (toggle) the selected code as you described. Of course you can set the key binding to something else like `alt + /` to keep the default block comment behaviour.

[image]

Tested with Visual Studio Code v1.50.1